# How to schedule the run of r script which reads data from postgres database, do some analysis and write resulting data to the database?

Tags: r, rscript

I have written a r script file, which reads in data from PostgreSQL database, do some analysis, predict the dependent variable and write back the results into the database. Now, I want to run that script file at fixed intervals. How to achieve this? Is there any way to run this from PostgreSQL or any other way to run this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:
https://github.com/bnosac/cronR - Unix/Linux 
https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR - Win